# Question regarding finding the net electrostatic field

Tags: electrostatics

While finding the **Net Electric Field $\vec{E}$** at a point P (question 2.5  in https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbD4L.jpg ),I get that we are trying to simplify our problem by ***cancelling out the horizontal components*** here at the beginning ,but ***if we don't cancel the horizontal components at the beginning and go along with what I did  for a second ,the components should cancel out eventually*** ,but I think I made some mistake here (please bear with me ,it's messy but I think you would understand what I've done here ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Mb8.jpg ,where have I gone wrong ?(I have tried to find the ***electric field $\vec{E}$ with respect to a coordinate system*** ,that's why $r$ in the **Coloumb's law** is $\vec{r}=z\hat{z} - r\hat{r}$ ,is this wrong?

Edit: I think I've realised my mistake ,$\hat{r}$ is $cosθ \hat{i} + sinθ \hat{j}$ ,when I substitute this before integrating the $2^{nd}$ term of the  expression ,I would've noticed the expression becoming zero as $sine$ and $cos$ are periodic functions and $0$ to $2π$ is their time period .Thank you for trying to help me .

Comment: Duplicate : [Electric field a distance  z  above the center of a circular loop. The Hard way](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66255/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric field a distance $z$ above the center of a circular loop. The Hard way](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66255/)

Comment: Duplicate 2 : [Simple Electric Field Problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/288654/).